# A dot seen in dplyr output, how to remove it?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using `dplyr` package on `iris` data set. I have seen the below output few times, does anyone know what does this `.` means in output? I tried getting the different syntaxes, but the result is still having that `.` character in it. How to remove it, where does it come from? Is it significant?

```
 iris %>% select(Species) %>% table
 # .
 #     setosa versicolor  virginica 
 #         50         50         50 

 iris %>% 
 select(Species) %>%
 table
 # .
 #     setosa versicolor  virginica 
 #         50         50         50 

 `%>%` (iris, select(Species)) %>% table
 # .
 #     setosa versicolor  virginica 
 #         50         50         50
```

Comment: When just `table(iris$Species)` is just not good enough anymore...

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes I know that above basic R method, I am exploring and curious where does this one comes from in `dplyr` output.

Comment: If you don't want the dot, you can use `iris %>% select(Species) %>% table(dnn = "")`. The `dnn = ""` is the only important part of it. You can also specify arbitrary names: `iris %>% select(Species) %>% table(Species_table = .)`

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thank you. Well what is it, it works, and if I put instead of `dnn` something else it doesn't work. Is it some kind of argument?

Comment: Read `?magrittr::\`%>%\`` for info on the `.`.

Comment: @Axeman I guess the dot you are talking about is related to formulas I guess.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to formulas.

Comment: @docendodiscimus Found the documentation for `dnn` in `table`